# Use of uninitialized value in a Perl script

Tags: linux, perl, unix

I have the below program for checking the file availability in a Unix directory.

```
my $numbera = "c://";
my $numberb = "test1.txt";
check_file_exist($numbera, $numberb);

sub check_file_exist {
    my $download_filename;
    my ($numbera,$numberb) = @_;
    $download_filename = $numbera.$numberb;
    print "*** $download_filename ****";
    my $mtime = (stat $download_filename)[9];
    my $filedatetime = scalar localtime $mtime;

    if (-e $download_filename) {
        print "Data File Exist which is created on $filedatetime";
    }
    unless (-e $download_filename) {
        print "File not exists";
    }
}
```

while running the program I am getting the below error:

```
*** data_file=HASH(0xa912f0)/home1/saravanan/ ****
Use of uninitialized value in localtime at /home1/saravanan/data_file.pl
```

Comment: `stat` will return an empty array if the file does not exist, which would make `$mtime` undef. You should probably move your `-e` check to earlier in the routine in any case. But does the test file exist?

Comment: Also the output `ContentFtpAlliance=HASH(0xa912f0)/home1/saravanan/` looks like you are calling the method differently to your example code e.g. `$self->check_file_exist(...` on an instance of a class? If so, that's an important detail, and you should add it!

Comment: text file is available in the directory

Comment: Hi Toolic, the above program is working fine in windows, but which is not working in linux environment.

Comment: How would you expect a windows path like `c://` to exist in linux?

Answer (score 2):

First, always put these in your program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

When you use *strict*, you will have to declare your variables with either `my` or `our` (HINT: You use `my` about 99.99% of the time).

These will catch all sorts of errors in your script:

Also, use indentations. It makes your script easier to read. It is also bad form to output inside of your subroutine (unless that is the purpose of your subroutine. Instead, have your subroutine return (or not return a value), and then display that.

Your problem is that you were attempting to `stat` a file before you knew whether it exists or not. You need to put your `stat` inside your `if` statement where you check for the file's existence.

I've made a few changes besides what I stated above:

- I use `say` instead of `print`. If you use `print`, you have to put in a terminating `\n`. The `say` command does this for you.
- I pull in my parameters as soon as I get the subroutine (and use better variable names than `$numbera` and `$numberb`.
- I use `if/then/else` instead of doing an `if` and then an `unless` with the same test. I no longer use `unless` in most circumstances. It's simply clearer to say `if ( not ... )`.
- The subroutine either returns a datestamp or returns nothing. I check for the return value of the subroutine with my `if` statement.

Here's your program updated a bit:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie;
use feature qw(say);
use Data::Dumper;

my $numbera = "/Users/david";
my $numberb = ".profile";

if ( my $timestamp = check_file_exist( $numbera, $numberb ) ) {
    say "The file was downloaded at $timestamp";
}
else {
    say "The file does not exist";
}

sub check_file_exist {
    my $directory = shift;
    my $file_name = shift;

    my $download_filename = "$directory/$file_name";

    my @stat = stat($download_filename);
    if (not @stat) {
         return;
    }
    my $mtime = $stat[9];
    return scalar localtime $mtime;
}
```

Comment: Seems to me the sub should simply be `sub get_mtime { my $qfn = shift; return ( stat($qfn) )[9]; }`. The rest belongs on the outside.

Comment: @ikegami I'm just trying to keep the program as much as the OP had it.

Comment: So you think it's ok saying the file doesn't exist when it might?

Comment: My personal preference is to die or croak if a subroutine or method does anything unexpected. However, that means wrapping the call in an eval to handle the *exception*. The older style for functions is to return something when it works and nothing if something doesn't work. In that case, it doesn't matter if the file exists and stat fails or the file just doesn't exist. I did it this way because I didn't want to get into using evals in this example.

Comment: Re: "it doesn't matter if the file exists and stat fails or the file just doesn't exist." How could you possibly know that?!